# SQL Query Difficult JOIN

Tags: sql

I am using the Lyric database. I need to list all the tracks of which a member named, Bryce Sanders plays.

The tables are as follows:

### Tracks

TitleID
TrackNum
TrackTitle

### Titles

TitleID
ArtistID
Title
StudioID
Genre

### Artists

ArtistID
ArtistName
City
Region
Country

### Members

MemberID
FirstName
LastName
Address
City
Region
Country
SalesID

### SalesPeople

SalesID
FirstName
LastName
Initials
Supervisor

Bryce Sanders is apart of the Members table. SalesID is a foriegn key of that table. Perhaps I can use SalesID in clever join to find the TrackTitles he has recorded.

Again the question is: I need to list all the tracks of which a member named, Bryce Sanders plays. And the database is Lyric.

My attempt to this is:

```
SELECT Members.Lastname, Members.FirstName, Tracks.TrackTitle 
FROM Members, Tracks 
WHERE Members.lastname = "Sanders";
```

But I do not think this completely solves it.

Comment: I think you need a `JOIN`, but I don't see which column connects `Members` and `Tracks`

Comment: Is this a database you designed? If not, are there any tables you forgot to mention?

Comment: This information is **not stored** in the schema you posted. It's missing a way to link a Member back to an Artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM tracks tr
INNER JOIN titles ti ON tr.titleID = ti.titleID
INNER JOIN artists ar ON tr.artistID = ti.artistID
INNER JOIN Members me ON me.artistID =  ar.artistID -- THIS IS MISSING. 
WHERE me.lastname = 'Sanders' AND me.firstname = 'Bryce';
```

You gotta have some way of joining MEMBER and ARTIST, and i don't see it in your question.
I wrote as example to add an artistID in Members to make it a part of an "Artist"

Comment: Thanks Mr. Silva for your response. It is extremely helpful and I appreciate your experience and intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

You need a transactions or sales table containing a list of the purchased tracks for each member. This table could also contain the if of the sales person.

There is no need for a sales person of on the members table. If sales persons are also members, then the foreign key should be the other way around, otherwise there should be no direct relationship between these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would have added a relation between tracks and sales.

### SalesItself

MemberID TrackID.

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at it based in your description is that `Members` and `Tracks` has a `many-to-many` type of relationship. And if that is the case then it's best to make a in-between table that would make two one-to-many relationship. In this case you could probably name it as `MembersTracks` table. This would mean that a `Member` would have many Tracks associated in `MembersTracks` table and a `Track` would have many `Members` associated with it.

The possible fields/columns for your `MembersTracks` table would be:

```
MembersTracksID (PK), MembersID (FK), TrackNum (FK), SubscriptionDate
```

And with that newly added in-between table you could probably make the query like this one:

```
SELECT M.Lastname, M.Firstname, T.TrackTitle
FROM MembersTracks MT
INNER JOIN Members M
ON MT.MembersID = M.MembersID
INNER JOIN Tracks T
ON MT.TrackNum = T.TrackNum
INNER JOIN Titles
ON T.TitleID = Titles.TitleID
WHERE M.Lastname = 'Sanders' AND M.Firstname = 'Bryce'
```